# JanRain Google+ error android

Tags: android, google-plus, janrain

I'm working with social login using janrain sdk for android. Implemented janrain sdk like writed in official docs! All work is success, but month ago start trouble. When I try choose google+ provider from provider list, I, receive "an iternal error ocurred." message. Anyone can reproduce this problem ? I have this bug alltime!